# Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I relatively new to programming and was following the installation guide https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10/.

This uses a linux subsystem(Ubuntu) on windows to run ruby on rails.

After I create a new rails app with `rails new <app_name> -d postgresql`

Everything seems to work until the last part when I try to `rake db:create` where it shows *could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?*
My *config/database.yml* has been edited to:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: postgres
  password: 
  host: localhost
```

My *postgresql.conf*  contains `listen_addresses = '*'` and *pg_hba.conf* contains `host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5`.
I have also tried to restart the postgreql service using windows services but nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have more then one instance of Postgres running? Where did you install Postgres from?  Are you connecting on the same machine as the server or from another machine? If from another machine is there a firewall in between?

Comment: Can you connect from the commandline using psql?

Comment: @Adrian Klaver I have installed from postgres.org windows installer. I'm connecting from the same machine and have created an inbound rule at port 5432. As far as I know i dont have more than 1 instance of postgres runing

Comment: @clamp Sorry im not sure what u mean by that as I am still quite new to this

Comment: Can you see in the Task Manager whether Postgres is running? If so as @clamp said try using `psql` to connect. `psql` is the Postgres command line program and will be in the Postgresql program group in the Start menu.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yeap it is running

Comment: So did you try connecting with `psql`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I did use `psql` and used the default servers and entered my password. It works.

Comment: Why is `servers` plural?  Do you mean you used something like `psql -d postgres -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432`? Is the Ruby app on the same machine?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Sorry it was a typo. What I did was go into the sql shell and entered a few times before typing my password. Ruby was created using ubuntu on the same machine.

Comment: Alright now I'm confused, I thought you are running on Windows?  Went to tutorial link and I see you are using Linux subsystem in Windows. That is the problem with links in a question and why they are discouraged. Include that information in the text of your question. So the problem is going from the Linux subsystem to Windows. From previous encounters with this, it is broken. Someone else may have a suggestion.  Personally I would stick with an all Linux solution.

Comment: I have edited the post to include more details. Thanks for the suggestion Adrian